# Pandas, time data ' ' or blanks does not match format

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do the following to make my data `20220620` into `2022-06-20 00:00:00` . Only problem is I believe the blanks in my column is leading me to this error: `time data '' does not match format '%Y%m%d' (match)`

Here is what I am trying,

```
 d7['date'] = pd.to_datetime(d7['date'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', errors='coerce')
```

Trying to bypass the blanks in my rows.

I know there are tons of threads on these but I haven't found one addressing `time data ''`.

Sample data:

```
       Date
0  20191101
1          
2  20191104
```

expected:

2019-11-01 00:00:00

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide a 5 rows example so I can try my idea out?

Comment: `d7.loc[d7['date'] != '', 'date'] = pd.to_datetime(d7['date'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', errors='coerce')`? I'm guessing here, I cba setting up a test case because you didn't either

Comment: That's not a test-case. How about just doing `pd.Dataframe({some_stuff_here})` so that people can actually copy/paste it into something runnable? That way, people can recreate the df directly and start testing. From what you provided, I still have to actually manually type it all out

Comment: does this work, `pd.DataFrame({'Date': [20191101, '', 20191104]})` ? or do you need something else?

Answer (score 2):

First you should consider the blank values and what you want to do with them.
Then remove `errors='coerce'` from `.dt.strftime` as it is not a valid argument for that method. 
You want to add the `errors='coerce'` to the `pd.to_datetime` part:

```
d7['date'] = pd.to_datetime(d7['date'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')\
               .dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Comment: dont think im allowed errors=coerce twice. i got an error `TypeError: strftime() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errors'`

Comment: That means its not an argument of strfttime(). You should remove it.

Comment: This seems to work! however in the blank rows im getting `NaT` and then im getting trailing decimals on my dates, ie `2022-06-20 00:00:00.00000`

Comment: Pandas is not wrong in telling you that those blank rows are Not a Time (NaT). 1. consider those blank values and what you should do with them: remove the row, change them to a specific date, etc. Understand where they are coming from, just like the 3013 date and deal with them. 2. As for the trailing decimal, that is coming from the '.%f' in your .dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'). Simply remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Sample data:

```
x = pd.DataFrame(data=['20191101', '20191104', '20191201', '', '20191205'], columns=['Date'])
x
       Date
0  20191101
1  20191104
2  20191201
3          
4  20191205
```

convert string to time with pd.to_datetime, then format the output using the dt.strftime method:

```
pd.to_datetime(x['Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

0    2019-11-01 00:00:00.000000
1    2019-11-04 00:00:00.000000
2    2019-12-01 00:00:00.000000
3                           NaT
4    2019-12-05 00:00:00.000000
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

[Link to strftime resource with the different time codes](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime)

Comment: thx ethan, was in x? The dataframe? Also is there a way not to include those trailing 0's? getting error `OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 3013-06-26 00:00:00`

Comment: x is the dataframe. I just used the format you provided. if you don't want trailing zero's, you can leave off the last part, '.%f' : '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'. if you don't want time at all, leave out the %H:%M:%S too :'%Y-%m-%d'. Also you're probably getting an error from a typo: your year is 3013.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this.  That is an actual year in my dataframe. Not sure how to get around it lol